# Performing higher level work

Tags: salary

I work at a small U.S. non-proft. My boss has been out on extended sick leave for six months and two other employees resigned this week taking us from a staff of seven to four available to work.  Is there any government regulation requiring they pay me more because of doing my supervisor's work and now taking on these other responsibilities as well?  Or is it just whatever the Board of Directors chooses to do?

Edit: I should have mentioned I am hourly part-time and my supervisor is salary full-time.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close because [questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694) are off topic here.

Comment: You can make the point that you are successfully discharging a number of additional responsibilities,  and you'd like your hourly rate to more closely reflect your added value to the organization. Alternatively, you'd like to be transferred to full-time status since you enjoy working for the organization. But then, that's not the question you are asking. The question you should be asking is "how do I ask for more money from the organization, given the circumstance?"

Comment: The answer to the question you are asking is "whatever the Board decides" and whatever the Board decides is organization specific. Which is why we are about to close your question.

Answer (score 2):

There's no regulation, especially if you're salaried. However it sounds like now is the perfect time to go speak to the Board of Directors or whoever is in charge of determining your compensation, and demand a raise. This might be a tougher sell than you might think, particularly if they have plans to immediately hire more workers (and depending on how replaceable you are). If you threaten to quit over the current situation, be prepared to follow through though.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am hourly part-time and my supervisor is salary full-time.